# Is ERC 20 smart contract apply mining pool rewards is scam

Tags: erc

I got notifications ERC 20 smart mining pool rewards 25ETH which is 46kusdt . When I click over there, my fox wallet money 11kusdt went to someone account. Then I spoken to customer service they given me telegram number. When I spoken on telegram, he told me u need to deposit another 18k usdt to get ur reward. I deposited 18k.so total money is 30kusdt. Even telegram guy told me ur funds will come to your account with in 24 hours Then when I click on withdraw that 76 k usdt should come to wallet. It's not come to wallet. When I spoken to manager on telegram, he told me, ur withdraw amount is too big. Ur account is locked u need to deposit another 15k usdt to unlock your account. UR funds will be release with in 2 hours. Does it scam or real I don't have any idea. Could someone elaborate on this.

Comment: Ah bro you got scammed in installments :)